# How to position <a> tag to the right inside <li> tag

Tags: css

Align the `<a>` tag inside `<li>` tag to the right.

Issue : `<a>` tag aligns immediately after the content of `<li>` tag . I want it to be placed evenly on to right on each li

example on jsfiddle :

[link to question](http://jsfiddle.net/8XSar/1/)

Comment: So you want your anchor tag to be right justified?

Comment: You mean like that? http://jsfiddle.net/8XSar/4/

Comment: Float it to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/NZg8m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `float:right` on the anchor element.

http://jsfiddle.net/8XSar/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
#cssmenu li a{
    /*background: #2580a2 url('hover.gif') left center no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    cursor : pointer;
    padding-bottom: 8px;*/
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    float:right;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8XSar/5/